# Renaming and Uploading File with Curl

Tags: curl, post

I want to upload a report.html to a jira ticket via a curl command. This works fine with this statement:

```
curl -u $JIRA_USER:$JIRA_USER_TOKEN -k -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=$SUREFIRE_REPORT_FILE" jira_url -R
```

I want to rename the file before attaching it to the ticket. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

(your `-X POST` in the command line is better removed)

You don't need to rename the file. You can tell curl to give the file a specific name in the upload by adding `;filename=yadayada` in the `-F` instruction.

I assume your `$SUREFIRE_REPORT_FILE` variable starts with a `@` to indicate that it is a file you're uploading. Then a command line could look like this:

```
FILENAME="yadayada.gif"
curl -u $JIRA_USER:$JIRA_USER_TOKEN -k \
     -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" \
     -F "file=$SUREFIRE_REPORT_FILE;filename=$FILENAME" \
     jira_url -R
```